Is it possible to obtain a comprehensive help / reference information about Clang using command line (e.g. man clang)?
While using GCC I usually use man gcc to find help / reference information (descriptions of command-line options, etc.). Most of the time the output of man gcc does contain help / reference information, which is present on https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/.
While using Clang I usually use man clang for the same purpose. However, usually the output of man clang doesn't contain the help / reference information, which is present on https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html.
Here is a comparison of the length of the output of man gcc vs. man clang:
$ man gcc | wc -l
18504

$ man clang | wc -l
436

Here we see that the output of man gcc is much bigger than the output of man clang.
Is it possible to obtain a comprehensive help / reference information about Clang using command line?

Extra:

I've tried info clang. However, it produces the same output than man clang.
The issue with https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html is than one needs to switch from the terminal to the web browser "back and forth". Perhaps, lynx https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html (then press / for search) can be the solution.


I suspect it's split into multiple man pages. See the SEE ALSO section for references to other man pages.

Thanks. The SEE ALSO may not always help. For example, I do believe that -frecord-command-line is a Clang option. However, man clang | grep frecord produces nothing (unexpected).

Of course, because it's in a different man page. SEE ALSO should list all the other related man pages.

I don't have the clang man page, I was just assuming it's split up like this. But I just looked at some online copies, they only refer to ld(1) and as(1). I suspect some of these -f options are undocumented and there just for GCC compatibility.

In the SEE ALSO section I see only as(1), ld(1). However, I'm on Cygwin. I'll check on Linux (Ubuntu) soon.

I just said the same thing.

Here is a solution that works for me:
$ alias "man_clang"="lynx https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html"

$ man_clang
<press '/' for search>

